# Link Multiple Either's

Tags: scala, either

Consider the scenario

```
trait Checker {
  def check()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Either[String, Unit]]
}
```

This trait is implemented by various class's.

Lets say

```
    class CheckerImpl1 extends Checker {
          override def check()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Either[String, Unit]] = ???
        }
    class CheckerImpl2 extends Checker {
          override def check()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Either[String, Unit]] = ???
        }
```

Now, I need to define a new function that will call `check()` function for each of these implementation classes in sequence(sequence does not matter) and return a new either i.e. `Future[Either[String, Unit]]` where String here is concatenated string of `left` for the `check()` implementation result.

So if `CheckerImpl1.check()` returns `Left("error1")` and `CheckerImpl2.check()` returns `Left("error2")` then result of the new function will return `Left("error1&error2")` (& just separate two strings).

OR

So if `CheckerImpl1.check()` returns `Right(())` and `CheckerImpl2.check()` returns `Left("error2")` then result of the new function will return `Left("error2")`.

OR

So if `CheckerImpl1.check()` returns `Right(())` and `CheckerImpl2.check()` returns `Right(())` then result of the new function will return `Right(())`.

What I have done right now is

```
(CheckerImpl1.check(), CheckerImpl2.check())
      .mapN {
        case (Right(_), Right(_))     => Right(())
        case (Left(err), Right(_))    => Left(err)
        case (Right(_), Left(err))    => Left(err)
        case (Left(err1), Left(err2)) => Left(err1 ++ "&" ++ err2)))
      }
```

But this is not a ideal solution, because if I add more implementation, then I would need to add more of these case statement.

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you eventually want to get `Future[Either[String, Unit]]` type. Why not just `.sequence` futures and `.fold` the results?

```
val checkers: List[Checker] = ???

Future.sequence(checkers.map(_.check()))
  .map { results => results.foldLeft(Right(()): Either[String, Unit]) {
    case (Left(acc), Left(err)) => Left(s"$acc&$err")
    case (Right(_), Left(err)) => Left(err)
    case (acc, Right(_)) => acc
  }}
```

The only code change you need now is to augment `checkers` list.

---

Somewhat *more* elegant using `cats` (if you are not familiar with [kind projector plugin](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector) - that's where the `*` comes from).

```
import cats.implicilts._

checkers.map(_.check()).sequence
  .map { results =>
    results.map(_.toValidatedNec)
      .sequence[ValidatedNec[String, *], Unit]
      .leftMap(_.toList.mkString("&"))
      .map(_ => ())
      .toEither
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

So you have a `List` of `Future` `Either`s.

```
val lfe :List[Future[Either[String,Unit]]] = ???
```

To get all the `Left` strings together in one `Future[String]` you could do this...

```
val res :Future[String] =
  Future.sequence(lfe)
        .map(_.flatMap(_.fold(Some(_),_ => None)).mkString(" & "))
```